# Finding Variance of Proportional Hazards Regression Coefficient Estimates in Weibull Regression

Tags: r, regression, variance, survival, weibull-distribution

So I am doing Weibull regression in R with the exponential relative risk function. The proportional hazards model formulation assumes that the hazard rate is given by $$\alpha(t;a,\sigma, \boldsymbol x_i) = \alpha_0(t;a,\sigma) exp(\boldsymbol \beta^T \boldsymbol x_i) = \frac{a}{\sigma}\bigg(\frac{t}{\sigma}\bigg)^{a-1} exp(\boldsymbol \beta^T \boldsymbol{x}_i)$$ where $\boldsymbol x_i$ is the vector of covariates for individual $i$, $a$ is the shape parameter and $\sigma$ is the scale parameter of the Weibull distribution with the parametrisation used in the rweibull function https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Weibull.html

The dataset I am using is the 'pbc' dataset found in the 'Survival' package in R, a short description of the dataset can be found on pages 76 and 77 here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/survival.pdf

A longer description and also some analysis of the data can be found in this study: https://aasldpubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/hep.1840200120

I fit my model in the following way:

```
library(survival)

data(pbc,package = "survival") # load the data


pbc_reduced = pbc[1:321,] # only interested in the first 321 cases

Survival = pbc_reduced$time

Censor = pbc_reduced$status



Censor[Censor == 1] = 0 # Individuals with status = 1 had a liver transplant and are to be considered censored

Censor[Censor == 2] = 1 # individuals with status = 2 died (survival time)

survobj = Surv(Survival,Censor)

pbc_weibull = survreg(survobj ~ trt + age + ascites + 
hepato + spiders + edema + bili + albumin + ast + 
protime, data = pbc_reduced, dist = "weibull")

summary(pbc_weibull)
```

The issue is that the coefficient estimates(and variances) of this model calculated by survreg are in accelerated failure time model form, and not in proportional hazards form, which is what I am interested in. A description of the difference can be found in section 10.3.7 in Moore(2016).

The coefficient estimates can be converted to proportional hazards form quite easily:

```
weib.coef = coef(pbc_weibull) # extract the coefficients of the model

weibcoef.ph = - weib.coef/pbc_weibull$scale # convert the coefficients to proportional hazards form
```

The regression coefficient estimates related to the covariates in proportional hazards form is given by $\hat{\beta_j} = -\hat{\gamma_j}/\hat{\kappa}$ where $\hat{\gamma_j}$ are the regression coefficient estimates returned by survreg, and $\kappa$ is what is called 'scale' in the survreg output.

I want to calculate confidence intervals for all the parameters in my model (in the proportional hazards formulation). Therefore, what I need help with is *calculating the variances and covariances of the $\hat{\beta_j}$ proportional hazards form regression coefficient estimates*.

Would greatly appreciate any help.